# C LuaJit Profiling

Tags: c++, c, linux, lua, profiling

I have following execution stack:

> 1. C++
> 2. C Lua API
> 3. LuaJIT
> 4. C functions - my own functions,  injected to Lua via C-Lua-API which called from lua script

I want to profiling this code. And I want to know percentage time spent in luajit phase.

I see come problems here. If I will compile luajit with flags something like -pg -fprofile-generate -fprofile-use it will be not the same that  luajit compiled for production build.

Is there any way to figure out what's going on in LUAJit phase?

Good example of this executions stack - [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: As example, u can see open-resty source.

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea use `perf` utility and [flamegraph](http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/cpuflamegraphs.html).
And there is no reason to recompile with `gcc` flags like `-fomit-frame-pointer`,  `-fprofile-generate`, `-fprofile-use`.

`perf` doesn't need this flags for collect information. Only `-pg` flag.